# Images overflow past their container

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I am trying to fit a set of images inside their container in a grid but for some reason the images overflow vertically past their container.

How can I make it so that they resize so they fit their parent's height?

```css
.images-container {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.images-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-container">
    <div class="images-column">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwEU.png" />
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwEU.png" />
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwEU.png" />
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwEU.png" />
  </div>
    <div class="images-column">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwEU.png" />
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwEU.png" />
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwEU.png" />
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwEU.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the images to fit inside the colored area vertically and allow scrolling horizontally if they overflow.

Here's the full [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jdo8hj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `flex-wrap: wrap`:

```
<div
  style="
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  "
>
  <img
    *ngFor="let image of allImages"
    [src]="image"
    style="
      object-fit: contain;
      max-height: 100%;
      height: auto;
      width: calc(25% - 10px);
      margin: 5px;"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive that just by setting the overflow property for the images container

```
.images-container {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: stretch;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

[Here is a jsfiddle solution for your question](http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/1/)

Comment: That just hides the images. I want the images to resize so that the `.image-column`s are the same height as the `.images-container`.

Comment: In my example the images fit perfectly in the parent's width. I'd like them to do the same but with the parent's height instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add

```css
flex-direction: row;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

to your image column field

Comment: That would not work, Please try to test your answers before you post them you can use [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) to test them